# How to create a 2d project in Cocos Creator 3.0

Tags: cocoscreator

I'm new to Cocos

I'm trying to create a 2d project. But, projects I created always in 3d like this:
[3d node](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zN23S.png)

How I can convert my empty 3d project to 2d project
Sorry for yy English not well!

Thank!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no separation between 2D and 3D projects.

### Node (v2.x.x only)

You can switch an individual node between 2D and 3D by clicking on the `3D` button in the top right corner in the `Properties` window.

[image]

### Scene view

To switch between 2D and 3D view in the scene, click on the `2D`/`3D` button near the top left corner of the editor.

[image]